# Thread.Sleep in aspx error page. Why?

Tags: asp.net, padding-oracle-attack

In [this advisory](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/advisory/2416728.mspx) concerning the oracle padding exploit, Microsoft posted the following recommended error page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Cryptography" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>

<script runat="server">
        void Page_Load() {
        byte[] delay = new byte[1];
        RandomNumberGenerator prng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        prng.GetBytes(delay);
        Thread.Sleep((int)delay[0]);

        IDisposable disposable = prng as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null) { disposable.Dispose(); }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        An error occurred while processing your request.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What's with the `Thread.Sleep` for some value between 0-255? I don't want my server threads tied up for up to quarter of a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is to alter the timing of the result. By making the return take a variable amount of time, you can't use the timing of the error return to determine the reason for failure, which is the approach that is used for the attack

Comment: OK, but couldn't the page then be used as a vector to exhaust your server of threads?

Comment: @spender: No, not more than any other page. It's normal for a page to wait for something as part of the rendering, for example a database result. Waiting for nothing isn't more expensive.

Comment: Given that this is all from 2010, and it's now 2012, has this vulnerability been fixed or should we leave the workaround as-is?

Comment: Based on the information on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-070 - it was addressed in an update for all supported releases.